# Use Fake to build and test an ASP.NET 5 / MVC 6 app?

Tags: asp.net, xunit.net, dnx, f#-fake

I am attempting to use FAKE to build and test a solution that includes an ASP.NET 5 / MVC 6 site (beta 8) and a unit test project for the site. I'm using the latest xUnit and have set up the xunit.runner.dnx command in my unit test project. Visual Studio can see the tests and run them without issue.

Using FAKE I've been able to get standard xUnit tests to run, but I'm unsure how to properly compile the site and run the DNX tests. If it matters, I'm targeting the full CLR, not just CORECLR.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What they basically do is create a DNX command that will run the unit tests in the context of a command line. You can see how they did it [there](https://github.com/xunit/dnx.xunit/tree/master/src/xunit.runner.dnx).

Now... if you want to run this in the context of Visual Studio, it's already built-in with MSTest Runner (haven't managed to make it work with ReSharper).

If you want to run the tests in command line mode, go to your test project folder (with `project.json` in there) and run `dnx test`.

As far as compilation goes, Roslyn will take care of it and you do not need to emit DLLs.

Comment: Following this, I have something working that's really basic: Shell.Exec("dnx", "--configuration Release -p ./tests/UnitTests test") |> ignore

Comment: Yes, that's the simplest thing that seems to work for running tests.

Comment: Best thing? It's cross-platform and you don't need a separate runner! It literally runs itself!

Comment: Combine this with a `gulp watch` command and you can re-run your tests as soon as a file in your solution/project changes. :)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at https://github.com/djanosik/FAKEX. It was designed to do FAKE builds on DNX.